# Set all members to private or public access mode in Java

Tags: java, c++, class, access-modifiers

In C++, I can use *public* and *private* access modifiers like this to set all members private together-

```
class myClass{
private:
int x;
int y;

void add(int X,int Y){
x += X;
y += Y;
}

public:
myClass(int X,int Y){
x = X; y = Y;
}
}
```

Is there a similar construct in Java, or do I have to set each function and member to public/private/protected separately?

(I can group similar ones like - *private int x,y;* *private float i,j;* etc)

Comment: No, there is no better solution than the one you provided.

Comment: You need to do it seperately.

Comment: i believe there is no other way, you have to define access level for each variable separatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set each function and member to public/private/protected separately.

You can still group them by modifier, if you like, although this would be purely to improve readability:

```
// Public
public int getTotal();
public final double MAX_X = 100;

//  Package
int foo;

// Privates
private int i,j;
private double x, y;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to mention it for each one. 
Similarly, it'll be

```
Class myClass {
    private int x;
    private int y;
}
```